# Polymorphic logger (virtual templated functions?)

Tags: c++, qt, c++14

**CONTEXT**

I have a library used by several software. Some are basic command line and some have a Qt UI.

I want to implement a unique log class inside this library, so every software can use it. However, if we are in a Qt environment, I'd like to use the `qDebug()` function with a specific `QtMessageHandler`.
The goal is to be able to log errors inside this library, and the logs will be printed differently, depending on if the library is used in a UI environment or not (the library has no dependencies to Qt).

---

**WHAT I WANT**

Globally, I want something like this:

```
class Logger
{
public:
    template <class T>
    void log(const T& tolog) { handler.log(tolog); }

    void setHandler(HANDLER???& h) { handler = h; }
    const HANDLER???& getHandler() const { return handler; }

private:
    HANDLER??? handler;
}
```

With the handler that will be, for command line software, something very simple like:

```
class CLHandler
{
public:
    template <class T>
    void log(const T& tolog) { out << tolog << std::endl; }

private:
    std::ostream out;
}
```

and for UI, I want to use `qDebug()` so I can setup a custom `QtMessageHandler` to print the error in the UI, and log it in a file:

```
class UIHandler
{
public:
    template <class T>
    void log(const T& tolog) { qDebug() << tolog; }
}
```

---

**PROBLEM**

As you can see, the problem is in the class `Logger`: what type will be the handler?

I can't really create an interface because of virtual template functions:

```
class IHandler
{
public:
    virtual ~IHandler() = default;

    template <class T>
    virtual void log(const T& tolog) = 0; // ERROR templated virtual function!
}
```

---

**Need help**

I want the `IHandler::tolog` function to be templated because I want to use the power of the `operator<<` for both `ostream` and `qDebug()`. And I don't want to reimplement all the overloads myself (long list for [ostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/), even longer for [qDebug](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html)!).

I want to achieve it, no matter how (lambda functions with `auto`?)... Any suggestions welcome (I may do something wrong here?).

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you considered making your logger class a template as well?

Comment: I don't think this is possible for my case but I may be wrong. I'd like the logger to be a singleton, so I can access it like that: `Logger::get().log()` (or something more beautiful). the thing is that both the library (which doesn't have Qt dependencies) and the software (with or without Qt) should use the same mean for logging errors.

Comment: But wouldn't each of both (library and Qt app) have their own instance of the logger anyway? Or are you going to register the logger in the library similarly as you register the handlers in the logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obviously not possible to have templated virtual functions, but you could use type erasure to "erase" the concrete type, so you don't need a template anymore.

Basically, you create an interface `ILoggableValue` that knows how to log your values both using `QDebug` and `std::ostream` streams, and use templates to generate concrete implementations for different types:

```
class ILoggableValue {
public:
    virtual ~ILoggableValue() = default;
    virtual void log(QDebug &os) const = 0;
    virtual void log(std::ostream &os) const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class LoggableValue : public ILoggableValue {
public:
    LoggableValue(const T &value) : value{value} {}
    void log(QDebug &os) const override {
        // implementation of log for QDebug goes here
        os << value;
    }
    void log (std::ostream &os) const override {
        // implementation of log for std::ostream goes here
        os << value << std::endl;
    }
private:
    const T &value;
};
```

Then, you create `IHandler` the same way you suggested it, but now you can use `ILoggableValue` to erase the template:

```
class IHandler {
public:
    virtual ~IHandler() = default;
    virtual void log(const ILoggableValue &tolog) const = 0;
};

class CLHandler : public IHandler {
public:
    explicit CLHandler(std::ostream &out) : out{out} {} 
    void log(const ILoggableValue &tolog) const override {
        tolog.log(out);
    }
private:
    std::ostream &out;
};

class UIHandler : public IHandler {
public:
    void log(const ILoggableValue &tolog) const override {
        tolog.log(qDebug());
    }
};
```

Finally, you use `IHandler` in your `Logger`:

```
class Logger {
public:
    Logger(std::unique_ptr<IHandler> h) : handler(std::move(h)) {}
    template <class T>
    void log(const T& tolog) { handler->log(LoggableValue<T>(tolog)); }

    void setHandler(std::unique_ptr<IHandler> &h) { handler = std::move(h); }
    const IHandler &getHandler() const { return *handler; }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<IHandler> handler;
};
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/0Urp1M) is a live example.

Comment: Very nice and ends in an elegant interface! Thanks a lot! :)